# How to select all children with class except the last one in css

Tags: css

http://jsfiddle.net/Lvq08t6d/

CSS:

```
div p.test:not(:last-child) {
    background: red;
}
```

I am trying to select all `p` with class `test` only except the last one and it's not working.

Fiddle with `:last-of-type`: http://jsfiddle.net/Lvq08t6d/1/ which didn't work for me.

Comment: I tried solution from both of those link and none of those worked for me...

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible with only CSS. Here is a way of using jQuery:

```js
$('.test:not(:last)').css('color', 'red');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <p class="test">The first paragraph.</p>
  <p class="test">The second paragraph.</p>
  <p class="test">The third paragraph.</p>
  <p class="test">The fourth paragraph.</p>
  <p class="test"><b>Note:</b> Internet Explorer 8 and earlier versions do not support the :nth-last-child() selector.</p>
  <p>another P here...</p>
</div>
```